# How to hide play button overlay on HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

With help earlier I fixed an issue with my video player about playing a video by clicking it, but I cannot figure out how to hide the play button overlay on click. Any help will be appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div class="video-wrapper">
  <video class="video" id="bVideo" loop controls>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
  <div class="playButton" onclick="playPause()"></div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
var bunnyVideo = document.getElementById("bVideo");

function playPause() { 
  if (bunnyVideo.paused)
  {         
     bunnyVideo.play();
     $(".playButton").toggle();
  }
  else 
  {
    bunnyVideo.pause();
    $(".playButton").toggle();
  }
} 

bunnyVideo.addEventListener("click", playPause, false);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gtoscano/ed9o52k5/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/ed9o52k5/3/

```
var bunnyVideo = document.getElementById("bVideo");

function playPause() {
  var el = document.getElementById("playButton");
  if (bunnyVideo.paused) {
    bunnyVideo.play();
    el.className ="";
  } else {

    bunnyVideo.pause();
    el.className = "playButton";
  }
}

bunnyVideo.addEventListener("click", playPause, false);
```